Copy response from Chrome Dev tools network tab
I am working with Typescript React.I want to copy paste a response into my react code as a mock-file.But when I copy from Network tab, the JSON response's keys are in double quotes.I want to convert this JSON response to a pure JavaScript object so that folding and unfolding works in my vs code.

When I copy this to vs code into my mock.ts file

I want the JSON in below format.(The double quotes of keys are removed)

How can I do this without manually editing/removing the double quotes?

Paste it somewhere like JSFiddle and parse it there.

JSON is by definition already valid JS, so just paste it in (e.g. const response = { "userId": 1, ... }; and then run a code formatter (like prettier) to force the correct code style, which will remove unnecessary quotes around object property names.

I'd consider prettier (code format tool). Can be used as a command (prettier write), or as IDE plugin, e.g. VS Code (will auto-format your code on Ctrl+S).
There is bunch of configs you can set, but object keys with no quotes is one of default rules if I reckon.


It worked when I changed the Prettier: Quote Props to "consistent". Thankyou
